# How to automatically set CreationDate on PDF

Tags: pdftex, datetime2

When compiling a document using pdflatex one can set the PDF CreationDate of the document using `\pdfinfo{...}`. I would like to automatically set this to the date supplied to `\date{...}` in the document.

One way to do this is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}

\title{My Title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\date{\DTMdisplaydate{2011}{12}{13}{-1}}
%\date{Winter 2011} % compiles, but results in blank CreationDate
%\date{\DTMdate{2011-12-13}} % compiles, but results in blank CreationDate due to robustness

\makeatletter
{\DTMsetstyle{pdf}
\pdfinfo{
    /Title  (\@title)
    /CreationDate (\@date 000000-05'00')
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle % typesets date in a US-style, as expected
\end{document}
```

But there are a couple of things that don't seem ideal about this solution. First, I needed to write `\@date 000000-05'00'` in order to convert the date into a full time with a time-zone (the time-zone is needed in order avoid dates being defined in UTC and then being displayed as one day earlier in the US). Second, I needed to use `\DTMdisplaydate` instead `\DTMdate` in order for the macro to expand.

Since this seems like a fairly standard thing to do, I was wondering what solutions other pdflatex users have developed.

Comment: The pgf calendar library has a number of formatting options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal approach would be to save the date like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}

\DTMsavetimestamp{creation}{2011-12-13T00:00:00-05:00}

\title{My Title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\date{\DTMusedate{creation}}

\makeatletter
{\DTMsetstyle{pdf}
\pdfinfo{
    /Title  (\@title)
    /CreationDate (\DTMuse{creation})
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle % typesets date in a US-style, as expected
\end{document}
```

You can provide a wrapper command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}

\newcommand{\mydate}[1]{%
  \DTMsavetimestamp{creation}{#1T00:00:00-05:00}%
  \date{\DTMusedate{creation}}%
  {\DTMsetstyle{pdf}%
  \pdfinfo{
    /CreationDate (\DTMuse{creation})
  }}%
}

\title{My Title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\mydate{2011-12-13}

\makeatletter
\pdfinfo{
    /Title  (\@title)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle % typesets date in a US-style, as expected
\end{document}
```

If you have a negative time zone, you'll need at least `datetime2` version 1.5.3 (2018-07-20) to avoid a bug that accidentally inserted `\relax` before the time zone.

Comment: When I compile either of the above (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)) and inspect the properties from Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (version 2018.011.20040) the creation date is blank. Is this a problem with robustness?

Comment: In case robustness was a problem I tried `\DTMsetstyle{pdf}\edef\foobar{\DTMuse{creation}}\pdfinfo{/CreationDate (\foobar)}` but AAR still shows "Created" as blank.

Comment: I tried @nicola-talbot suggestions on an older TeXLive installation (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX)) and it still resulted in a blank "Created:" field in AcroRd32.exe.

Comment: @banbh pdfinfo, okular and evince all have the creation date set correctly with the above. I have TeX Live 2018 running on Fedora 27. With your `\foobar` example, try `\show\foobar` after you define it. That should show the fully expanded date in the transcript.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the suggestion. There is a `\relax` in it; in fact `\foobar` is `D:20111213000000\relax -05'00'` and indeed `\pdfinfo{/CreationDate (D:20111213000000\relax -05'00')}` does not produce a date in AcroRd32.exe. Also, `\edef\foobar{\DTMusedate{creation}000000-05'00'}` followed by `\pdfinfo{/CreationDate (\foobar)}` works. I'm curious, why does `\DTMuse` insert a `\relax` before the time-zone?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that doing what I described in my previous comment *does* make the 'Created:' field appear populated, but with the same time as the 'Modified:' field! However copying the output of `\show\foobar` into the `\pdfinfo` works as expected. At this point, I am at a loss to explain what is going on. As soon as I have some time I will upgrade to TL2018 and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @banbh That `\relax` is the problem. Thanks for noticing that. I'll get that fixed. I'm guessing that pdfinfo is more tolerant about skipping the malformed part.

Comment: @banbh Now fixed in datetime2 v 1.5.3. (It will take a few days for it to reach the TeX distributions.)

Comment: @banbh I forgot to add, the reason for the `\relax` is due to a missing space in the time zone style `\ifnum##1<0\else+\fi` needs to be `\ifnum##1<0 \else+\fi`. It's a by-product of the way TeX parses numbers.

Comment: I just tested datetime2 v1.5.3 and the above documents now correctly result in a date that is displayed by AcroRd32.exe -- thanks!