# Change PDF timestamp in ConTeXt

Tags: pdf, context, metadata

Inspired by the [corresponding question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440389/how-to-automatically-set-creationdate-on-pdf) for pdftex, I want to set the pdf timestamp in the metadata in ConTeXt.

What didn't work so far:

```
% Set the luatex variables, applies only to \date
\ctxlua{
pt=string.gmatch('2018-04-22','[^-]+');
tex.year=tonumber(pt());
tex.month=tonumber(pt()); % month is ignored by ConTeXt
tex.day=tonumber(pt());
}

% set the PDF metadata, but the time isn't set.
\setupinteraction[state=start, title={This gets shown}, date=2018-04-22T15:42:12+01:00]

\starttext
\date % April 22, 2018
\stoptext
```

Here the set data is displayed correctly, but the pdf timestamp is still the current date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some looking through `lpdf-ini.lua`, `lpdf-xmp.lua` and `back-ini.lua` I've found a way to change the metadata:

```
% Change PDF metadata timestamp, 
\startluacode
local metadata = lpdf.getmetadata();
metadata['time'] = '2018-04-22T15:42:12+01:00';
\stopluacode
```

This doesn't touch the `\currentdate` set by TeX, so you can have different dates for `\date` and the metadata. The date format is PDF specific, so this will break other output formats.