# Context Metadata pdf

Tags: context, metadata

After visiting this question [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470541/change-pdf-timestamp-in-context)

I was wondering where I could find all the fields, to be able to edit the pdf metadata generated with ConTeXt

Answer (score 1):

You can simply inspect the return value of `lpdf.getmetadata` to explore all the defined fields.

```
\starttext
\startluacode
local metadata = lpdf.getmetadata()
inspect(metadata)
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

This will leave the following in the log file

```lua
table={
 ["contextversion"]="2021.03.05 19:11",
 ["creator"]="LuaTeX 1.13 7430 + ConTeXt MkIV 2021.03.05 19:11",
 ["luatexfunctionality"]="7430",
 ["luatexversion"]="1.13",
 ["luaversion"]="5.3",
 ["platform"]="linux-64",
 ["producer"]="LuaTeX-1.13",
 ["time"]="2021-05-25T20:10:31+02:00",
}
```

To set the title and author metadata it is better to use

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\startdocument
  [metadata:title={Title},
   metadata:subtitle={Subtitle},
   metadata:author={Author},
   metadata:date={Date}]

  ...

\stopdocument
```

instead of `\start...\stoptext`, because this will also update the XMP data in case you are creating tagged PDF.

Comment: Thank you I can get the meetadata, but I can't "overwrite" them. If I copy and paste your code and compiling the generated PDF, looking with Adobe Acobat, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Zezzo Which code? Note that for the `\startdocument` bit you also need `\setupinteraction[state=start]`. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Okay, I undestand, but actuallu I can't really understand how to put those string of text in  code