# Why does xelatex produce a different binary of the pdf each time?

Tags: xetex, pdf

This is doc.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

Then I `xelatex doc.tex` and `md5 doc.pdf`, so I get a unique md5  code. If I run xelatex again on the same tex file it produces a diff pdf (diff md5).

What can I do for xelatex to procude the same md5 result for the same tex file?

Comment: The pdf tends to contain a creation date/time that will change with each run.

Comment: Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440389/15925 helps

Comment: This as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229605/

Comment: @Claudio I'd say the current question is a duplicate of that one, do you agree?

Comment: @Marijn I agree